# Load Image OpenCV (JavaCV) from byte[] not a file

Tags: java, opencv, arrays, javacv

I have image data coming in from over a socket connection as a byte[]. All examples I have seen using `cvLoadImage()` is passed a file name. Do I have to save every image to file and re-open it to do the processing? This seems to have a lot of overhead for what needs to happen, is it possible to load the image from the byte[] data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution in the end, you can use the following method to create an Image from a BufferedImage which solved my problem:

```
IplImage src = IplImage.createFrom(buffered);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is encoded in some standard format like JPG or PNG, and assuming you are using JavaCV, for a byte array b, this works as well:

`IplImage image = cvDecodeImage(cvMat(1, b.length, CV_8UC1, new BytePointer(b)));`